# Usage of the .W suffix in ARM assembler

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I'm reading the Instruction set manual, and am wondering about the `.W` suffix.

The manual says:

> In some cases it might be necessary to specify the .W suffix, for
>   example if the operand is the label of an instruction or literal data,
>   as in the case of branch instructions. This is because the assembler
>   might not automatically generate the right size encoding.

I can't think of any reason why I'd *need* to override the assembler's default encoding. What I've tried so far always compiled fine without `.W`.

Did they really add a special syntax to overcome a possible bug in the assembler (maybe meanwhile fixed)?

Can you provide some example where I have to explicitly use .W (Thumb2 on Cortex-M3).

Comment: it helps the assembler clearly understand when there is a choice between thumb and thumb2.   just look at the B encoding/instruction in the ARM ARM and you can see the difference.   all variants offers an 8 or 11 bit immediate depending on conditional or unconditional.  the thumb2 extension offers 16 or 21 bits of immediate depending on conditional or not.  by using .w you are indicating you want the thumb2 and not let the assembler guess.   nevertheless I would call it a bug if the assembler guesses wrong in this case.

Comment: for known labels at assemble time it knows what it must encode.  for external labels it can burn the halfword to reduce the change of the linker having issues or having to add stuff.  But the gcc linker at least now adds a trampoline if needed to get to the desired address.  maybe arms assembler/linker is not as good as gnu in this case (or at the time of the writing of the manual)

Comment: a simple add without the .w can at times be encoded with either thumb or a thumb2 extension (a case where gnu fails us before or without the unified syntax), if you specifically want the thumb2 extension for some reason, you force that with the .w

Comment: thumb2 extensions are found on m0, m0+, m1, m3, m4, m7 and the cortex-a's as well or at least some of them.  what number varies.  the armv6m (cortex m0/m1) do not have a thumb2 extension for branch for example.  but m3/m4(/m7) do.

Comment: Disagree on the dupe - "what does this do?" and "_why_ would you want to do that?" are closely related for sure, but they definitely stand as separate questions.

Comment: @Notlikethat The other questions answers also touch on the 'why' part.  There is also the a `.n` suffix as well.  They are all alternate encodings; do we want a *what* and a *why* question for every alternative thumb2 encoding?  This question should be linked to the other one, so your good answer still stands.

Comment: To who marked this as duplicate - also note that the "duplicated" question is about a completely different syntax - "addw" is not "add.w"

Comment: @MightyPork Yes, they are different alternate encodings (but the same concept).  You proved my point.  Do we want a separate what/why question for every `.n`, `.w` and `w` alternate encoding.  The answer here (by Notlikethat) would fit the other question.  When answering the 'what' question, you may naturally answer the 'why'.

Comment: Well, as long as this question and the good answer stays, I don't really mind it being marked as a "duplicate"...

Comment: @artlessnoise Having separate "what is X?" vs. "when should I use X?" questions is already a common pattern, because there's a clear logical distinction. `add`/`addw` is a special case of horrible instruction-specific syntax - `.n`/`.w` can be answered generally (neither the question nor answer here mention a specific mnemonic, nor do they need to).

Comment: @Notlikethat Auslen's answer in the other question would also answer this question?  If you can move answer/questions around and they still make sense, that is a criteria for a duplicate.

Comment: @artlessnoise I guess the difference is that I read this question as implying that the OP has already fully understood what the syntax itself means. Under that interpretation the dupe flag represents this: _"Q: Why does this manual suggest I might sometimes need to force an assembler to pick an encoding other than the default one for a given label operand? Under what circumstances could that ever be necessary? A: That syntax lets you force an assembler to reproduce a particular encoding (instead of automatically choosing the 'best' one for the given operands)"_. Nope, sense no make.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.W` suffix is still *necessary* in the syntax, even if most people will never use it explicitly, in order to maintain the behaviour that disassembling any valid code and passing the resulting source back through the assembler results in the exact same instructions again. Thus every valid instruction encoding must have some way of being represented unambiguously in the language, even if it isn't the preferred one the assembler would choose by default for the base mnemonic and operands. And of course, because it exists in the syntax, then you don't have to go writing machine code directly or patching binaries to get those encodings in the first place.

Now, there are various esoteric reasons for wanting non-preferred encodings in the final binary - things like tweaking instruction alignment, using code as data, etc. - but the least crazy one is probably relocations. If you have a branch to an external symbol, or a symbol in a different section, the assembler doesn't necessarily know how far away that symbol is going to end up. Therefore it has to choose between emitting a narrow instruction which may end up unlinkable, or a wide instruction which may end up wasting code space if the target ends up close enough. Both GNU as and armasm seem to go for the latter, although it's not that hard to imagine some specialised embedded assembler defaulting to the former for size reasons.

Runtime relocations are an even stronger argument: you have a branch or literal load which *is* resolved at assembly time, but you might want to hotpatch under certain circumstances to target something else. That could require the extra range of a wide encoding even when the original target lies within range of a narrow one.

Comment: I think first a few sentences are too strong. I mean it should work on instruction level but claiming you'll get the same binary blob is probably too much stretch. At least you can't make that kind of claim just over the usage of .W suffix.

Comment: @auselen True, "object file" is too broad without the specific context that was in my head at the time. Still, having disassembly/reassembly be idempotent in terms of the instructions is certainly a feature specifically designed into the language; see also the weird two-part syntax for modified immediate constants that nobody knows about.

Comment: I agree, you have a very nice explanation here, just early sentences might be very misleading for less informed. otherwise nice as always.